# Why I am getting the error 'Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]' in the backend?

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I am building an Ecommerce webpage and now working on the payment part. I have created the controller and router, but getting the error

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (F:\zebrow_mern\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\zebrow_mern\backend\routes\paymentRouter.js:9:34)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

This is my controller

```
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middleware/catchAsyncError");

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const processPayment = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const myPayment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: "inr",
    metadata: {
      company: "Zebrow",
    },
  });

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ success: true, client_secret: myPayment.client_secret });
});

exports.sendStripeApiKey = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({ stripeApiKey: process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY });
});
module.exports = {processPayment}
```

Router file

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  processPayment,
  sendStripeApiKey,
} = require("../controllers/paymentController");
const router = express.Router();
const { isAuthenticatedUser } = require("../middleware/auth");

router.route("/payment/process").post(isAuthenticatedUser, processPayment);

router.route("/stripeapikey").get(isAuthenticatedUser, sendStripeApiKey);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It has to do with mixing `exports.sendStripeApiKey` and `module.exports`. By using `module.exports` you're overwriting `exports` (which is a reference to module.exports -- therefore the `sendStripeApiKey` property becomes undefined). I'd recommend sticking to one pattern: `module.exports = { processPayment, sendStripeApiKey }` or `exports.processPayment` and`exports.sendStripeApiKey`.

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fehv0rxt/) to demonstrate what's happening in your code above (click the `Console (beta)` tab to expand and view the logs).

Comment: I have tried all the ways but still getting the same error :( Please help me!

Comment: When i remove isAuthenticatedUser inside post, the error is gone. Can anyone explain why? But the  isAuthenticatedUser  is working with my other routes fine

Comment: I’d recommend console logging the import `isAuthenticatedUser` and ensuring it’s a function and not an object. On that note, it’s hard to determine where your problem lies, since you haven’t included all of the code involved in the above error. If you have a GitHub repo, please share it; otherwise, please create a small reproduction of the error.